# Java Web Start sessions

Tags: servlets, java-web-start

I have a jws-applets app. I need to send data to a servlet. My problem is that when I open a new windows (redirect to a servlet), the web browser create a new session. I need that the browser use the same session of the jws-applet app. I have no idea of what to do. Any help?

Comment: What "session" exactly are you talking about? There are SO MANY sessions in an average Java EE application. HTTP session? JWS session? Applet session? JPA/DB session? EJB session? WS session? Whatever session?

Comment: This is strange. It's not the default behavior. Next step to naildown the cause would be investigating the HTTP traffic (press F12 in webbrowser and open *Network*) and checking if the JSESSIONID cookie behaves as per the specification. Perhaps you're somewhere somehow invalidating/renewing it, or the redirect conflicts with cookie path. Who knows. You're the only one who can tell this.